# Ember.JS, display views depending on the user role

Tags: mongodb, ember.js

I am using Ember.Js to create a web application, I have User collection in my MongoDb, in User collection there is a Role attribute which can take two values, "admin" or "customer".
What I want to do is the following : 
When someone logs in, he is going to be redirected either to the admin dashboard or customer interface, depending on his Role.

How can I achieve this ? what is the best practice ?
It is a good idea or I should better create a collection for admin and another for customer ?

Comment: Look into [`Route.afterModel`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/redirection/#toc_after-the-model-is-known) or [`Route.renderTemplate`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/rendering-a-template/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally make use of the Application route's `afterModel` hook.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        //I DK if you use Ember Data. I don't but this could be a store lookup.
        return this.userService.getCurrentUser()
    },
    afterModel: function(resolvedModel, transition){
        var user = resolvedModel;
        if(user.role === 'ADMIN'){
            this.transitionTo('admin-dashboard');
        }else{
            this.transitionTo('customer-interface');
        }
    }
});
```

You could then have different menu structures that only link-to admin and customer routes respectively or both. I'd also have a mixin that all of my other Admin only routes extend:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    beforeModel: function(){
        var currentUser = this.modelFor('application');
        if(currentUser.role !== 'ADMIN'){
            //handle this howerver
            this.transitionTo('unauthorized');
        }
    }
});
```

So your `admin-dashboard` route would look like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AdminRoute from 'app_name/mixins/admin-route';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AdminRoute, {});
```